# How to enumerate DCE services on open port 135?

Tags: nmap, enumeration

I did a vulnerability scan on a machine and found a DCE Services Enumeration vulnerability.  This is described as:

> Distributed Computing Environment (DCE) services running on the remote host can be enumerated by connecting on port 135 and doing the appropriate queries.
>
> An attacker may use this fact to gain more knowledge about the remote host.

Other than a typical banner grab/service enumeration with nmap like:

```
nmap -sV -sT <ip>
```

How can I actually enumerate services with this vulnerability?

Comment: You misunderstand the vulnerability.  The DCE service may provide you with a list of services running on the machine, they will not be all running on port 135.

Comment: @grochmal Ahh I see, so how does one use the DCE service to enumerate all other services on the machine?

Comment: Is this question a repeat of -- http://security.stackexchange.com/q/93542/140 -- ?